# Como exportar una funcion de un archivo js a otro archivo js

Tags: javascript, funciones

Necesitaria un ejemplo basico de como exportar una funcion de un archivo js a otro.
Supongamos tengo dos archivos: main.js, y operar.js
En el archivo principal.js yo desarrolle una funcion y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de no copiar dos veces el mismo codigo y simplemente exportar esa funcion en el archivo secundario.js sin volver a desarrollarla.
Tambien necesito saber si debo poner algo en el script en mi html porque he visto varios videos pero ninguno me resolvio el problema.

archivo main.js

```
import { prueba } from './operar';
```

archivo operar

```
import { prueba } from './main';
prueba();
```

Yo estoy tratando de importarlo y me sale este error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Hola Kevin, estas utilizando un framework en especifico? Basado en tu código parece ser que estas trabajando con algún framework de JavaScript.Es importante que incluyas esa información para que la comunidad te de claramente una respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

> Yo estoy tratando de importarlo y me sale este error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Los métodos **import/export** rquieren de mayo énfasis en la llamada de los recursos (`src`) especificando con un `type="module"`.
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Module Kevin Cánepa</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Abrir Consola...</h1>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
import myFunc from './main_second.js';
myFunc();
```

**main_second.js**

```
export default function () { console.log("Nice job") };
```

Te en cuenta que el uso de `import y export` de [ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp) trae consigo ciertos detalles a tener en cuenta dependiendo tu proyecto.

> Ya no podrá correr un archivo .html de forma normal y corriente, solo
>   podra correr su archivo .html en un servidor. [@Riven](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353796/como-exportar-una-funcion-de-un-archivo-js-a-otro-archivo-js/353833#comment637738_353833)

Comment: la importacion que tienes fallaria, te falta un pequeño detalle.

Comment: Hey, Riven. Dime cual es el fallo y lo comprobare.

Comment: De hecho no he visto que nadie en las respuestas que ha puesto explique un pequeño detalle que hay que tener en cuenta a la hora de usar import y export de ES6, por eso es bueno explicarlo tambien para ponerlo como complemento por aqui..., pero este pequeño detalle puede hacer que las importaciones y exportaciones de ES6 no funcionen, en el caso de estas (import y export de ES6), no se ha explicado que el usuario ya no podrá correr un archivo .html de forma normal y corriente, solo podra correr su archivo .html en un servidor, de lo contrario import y export no funcionaran.

Comment: Ah el fallo es pequeño, lo que pasa es que la sentencia import, si apuntas a una carpeta en el mismo directorio, siempre debe llevar como minimo un punto al inicio, o 2 si se trata de devolverse un directorio, no se porque lo hicieron asi, puesto que es mas comodo sin un solo punto si se trata de un archivo en el mismo directorio, pero por ese punto que no hay al inicio la carga del modulo fallara, la ruta deberia ser ./main_second.js

Comment: Son recomendaciones que doy para aportar a tu respuesta, porque pienso que tu respuesta se destaca, felicidades Link.

Comment: Vaya, esto es muy cierto. siguiendo mi lógica no asigne ninguno punto ya que se encuentra en el mismo en el directorio, claro, Javascript piensa diferente. Lo editare. En cuanto a la limitación que trae consigo el uso del import y export en el recorrido del .html me párese un gran dato adicional a incluir. Anclare tu respuesta. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Ya tienes respuestas buenas sobre el asunto, pero te daré esta que tiene un enfoque diferente de cara a la falta de soporte de estas características aún hoy en día.

No todos los navegadores soportan las características de [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015) en la cual se da soporte a los llamados módulos.

Sin embargo, no es necesario el uso de los mismos para reutilizar código en tu página web.

Lo que debes tener presente es el llamado ámbito global y verificar que las funciones que deseas utilizar sean llamadas en el orden correcto y en el momento adecuado (ojo con la asincronía).

Si no existiera esta posibilidad, no hubieran existido frameworks o librerías como [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) por ejemplo.

Dicho esto, supongamos que tienes una función que vas a utilizar recurrentemente en tu aplicación, no tiene sentido escribirla para cada archivo JS que vayas a cargar mediante el atributo `src` de la etiqueta `script`.

Lo que puedes hacer es escribir todas estas funciones utilitarias en un archivo llamado `utils.js`, y asegurarte que el mismo es cargado antes que el resto de tus archivos JS que usan las funciones de `utils`.

Por ejemplo:

**Archivo `utils.js`**:

```js
function getDate() {
  return new Date();
}
function getWindowLocation() {
  return window.location;
}
```

Tengo 2 funciones en mi archivo `util.js` y como ambas están definidas mediante la declaración explícita de funciones, las mismas son elevadas (`hoisted`) al ámbito global (`window`), por lo tanto estarán disponibles en cualquier ámbito declarado dentro de `window`.

**Archivo `main.js`**

```js
const dateDIV = document.getElementById('date');
const locationDIV = document.getElementById('location');

dateDIV.textContent = getDate();
locationDIV.textContent = getLocation();
```

En mi archivo `main.js` utilizo las 2 funciones que fueron declaradas en mi archivo `utils.js`.

Este código funcionará siempre que el orden en el que cargo mis *scripts* sea el correcto.

**Archivo `index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Modules</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="date"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="location"></div>
  <!-- Primero debo cargar utils.js -->
  <script src="utils.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedes apreciar, he cargado en primer lugar el *script* del archivo `utils.js` y luego el de `main.js`.

Así, no necesitas usar realmente las sentencias `import` y `export` que son parte de la especificación ES6. Solo debes asegurarte de cargar tus archivos en el orden adecuado.

Uno de los problemas de esta forma de trabajar, es que si tu aplicación crece demasiado, será difícil llevar el control de todas las variables, métodos y objetos que ocupan el ámbito global, y acabas teniendo problemas con el llamado *Global Namespace Pollution*. Existen técnicas para evitar esto, pero ya eso es otro tema.

**Nota**, en el ejemplo, se asume que los 3 archivos (`index.html`, `utils.js` y `main.js`) se encuentran en la misma carpeta (sea local o remota).

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte!!

Comment: +1 es muy útil esta información para nuevos usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso `module.exports` en el archivo en que quiero compartir cosas y `require` donde quiero utilizarlas.

**operar.js**

```
var prueba = function () {
  console.log('probando...');
};

module.exports = { prueba };
```

**main.js**

```
var op = require('./operar');
op.prueba();
```

Ahora, en la línea de comandos:

```sh
node main.js
```

Aunque a mí no me gusta, también puedes hacer `module.exports = prueba;` en operar.js y luego `var prueba = require('./operar');` en main.js. Así puedes llamar a la función directamente con `prueba()` en vez de `op.prueba()`.

Comment: Esto solo funcionaria si el usuario esta usando nodejs.

Comment: En el navegador no hay una manera de hacerlo que la acepten todos los navegadores. Como siempre, te dejarías IE fuera. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando nodejs te recomiendo que uses la inclusión por `Common JS` (module.exports/require) y si estás en browser `JS modules`(import/export)

### Teniendo el siguiente código

```js
function pepe() {

}

function lala() {

}
```

#### Common js

`module.exports = {pepe, lala};`
`const Mimodulo = require('ruta del módulo');`

#### Js modules

`export {pepe, lala};`
`import * as Mimodulo from 'ruta del módulo';`

**Nota**: En los js modules en el html tienes que poner dentro de la etiqueta `<script>` `type="module"` y la ruta del script con `src="ruta"`. Te animo a que indagues un poco más sobre ambas formas de inclusión.

Comment: Menos mal se especifica el uso de nodejs...